# Merging data sets based on Timestamp

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have two data sets with timestamps that I would like to merge. For every value in column `X` in `df2` I want to have a value for `Jar` and `Treatment` from `df1`. From `df1` I can see which `Jar` was measured and what the `Treatment` was at a specific time. In `df2` I can see what the value of `X` was at a specific time and I need to know what `Jar` (and which `Treatment`) was measured when I see a specific value of `X`.

I have tried a bit with `full_join`, but since there are gaps in the time series this does not work. E.g. in `df2` there is a value of `X` at Timestamp: 2020-12-16 14:31:05, but this Timestamp is not present in `df1`. Based on df1 however, I know that at this Timestamp `Jar=Soil_dry` and `Treatment=None`.

Any suggestions as how to make a table where I can get a value of `Jar` and `Treatment` in `df1` for every of my `X` values in `df2`?

Here's df1:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Jar = c("Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", 
"Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", 
"Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", 
"Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", "soil_wet", "soil_wet", "soil_wet", 
"soil_wet", "soil_wet", "soil_wet", "soil_wet", "soil_wet", "soil_wet", 
"soil_wet", "soil_wet", "soil_wet", "soil_wet", "soil_wet", "soil_wet", 
"soil_wet", "soil_wet", "soil_wet", "soil_wet", "soil_wet", "Soil_dry", 
"Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", 
"Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", "Soil_dry", 
"Soil_dry", "soil_wet", "soil_wet", "soil_wet", "soil_wet", "soil_wet", 
"soil_wet", "soil_wet", "soil_wet", "soil_wet", "soil_wet", "soil_wet", 
"soil_wet", "soil_wet", "soil_wet", "soil_wet"), Treatment = c("None", 
"None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", 
"None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", 
"None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", 
"None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", 
"None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "ul5", "ul5", 
"ul5", "ul5", "ul5", "ul5", "ul5", "ul5", "ul5", "ul5", "ul5", 
"ul5", "ul5", "ul5", "ul5", "ul5", "ul5", "ul5", "ul5", "ul5", 
"ul5", "ul5", "ul5", "ul5", "ul5", "ul5", "ul5", "ul5", "ul5"
), Timestamp = structure(c(1608128877, 1608128933, 1608128997, 
1608129058, 1608129063, 1608129112, 1608129117, 1608129122, 1608129127, 
1608129238, 1608129243, 1608129348, 1608129353, 1608129358, 1608129363, 
1608129368, 1608129373, 1608129473, 1608129478, 1608129483, 1608129488, 
1608129598, 1608129603, 1608129717, 1608129723, 1608129837, 1608129842, 
1608129957, 1608129962, 1608130072, 1608130077, 1608130082, 1608130192, 
1608130197, 1608130202, 1608130318, 1608130323, 1608130418, 1608130423, 
1608130428, 1608130492, 1608130497, 1608130502, 1608130507, 1608130612, 
1608130617, 1608130622, 1608130627, 1608130732, 1608130737, 1608130742, 
1608130747, 1608130853, 1608130858, 1608130863, 1608130978, 1608130983, 
1608131093, 1608131098, 1608131103, 1608131213, 1608131218, 1608131223, 
1608131337, 1608131343, 1608131457, 1608131462, 1608131467), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -68L), class = "data.frame")
```

df2:

```
df2 <-structure(list(X = c(5L, 3L, 34L, 4L, 65L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 
8L, 5L, 78L, 9L, 5L, 78L, 9L, 5L, 78L, 9L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 34L, 8L, 
5L, 4L, 9L, 78L, 59L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 47L, 2L, 67L, 
34L, 76L, 5L, 76L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 13L, 1L, 54L, 32L, 4L, 
3L, 45L, 1L, 1L), Timestamp = structure(c(1608129065, 1608129122, 
1608129127, 1608129238, 1608129263, 1608129288, 1608129353, 1608129358, 
1608129363, 1608129368, 1608129373, 1608129473, 1608129478, 1608129483, 
1608129488, 1608129598, 1608129663, 1608129717, 1608129723, 1608129831, 
1608129842, 1608129957, 1608129962, 1608130072, 1608130073, 1608130082, 
1608130132, 1608130197, 1608130202, 1608130318, 1608130323, 1608130418, 
1608130423, 1608130428, 1608130492, 1608130497, 1608130502, 1608130507, 
1608130612, 1608130617, 1608130622, 1608130627, 1608130732, 1608130737, 
1608130742, 1608130747, 1608130853, 1608130858, 1608130863, 1608130978, 
1608130983, 1608131093, 1608131098, 1608131103, 1608131213, 1608131218, 
1608131223, 1608131337), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, -58L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Since df1 and df2 have only column "Timestamp" in common, are you trying to merge both by the "Timestamp" column?

Comment: Does `merge(df1, df2)` give you what you want?

Comment: The problem with ```merge(df1, df2)``` is that there are missing Timestamps. E.g., df2 has an value of X at 2020-12-16 14:27:52, but since this Timestamp is not present in df1, the X measurement is not present in the outcome of ```merge(df1, df2)```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why doesn't `df3 <- df1 %>%  full_join(df2, by = 'Timestamp')`  yield the result you want?

Furthermore, you state

> I need to know what Jar/Treatment was measured when I see a specific value of X.

In several cases, you have multiple values of Timestamp for a given value of X. In other words, you can't avoid getting multiple Jar/Treatment measures for each X value.

Example:

| Timestamp | Jar | Treatment | X.df1 | X.df2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-16 15:03:03 | soil_wet | ul5 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-12-16 15:07:03 | soil_wet | ul5 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-12-16 15:08:57 | soil_wet | ul5 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-12-16 14:56:52 | Soil_dry | ul5 | 2 | 2 |
| 2020-12-16 15:01:03 | soil_wet | ul5 | 2 | 2 |
| 2020-12-16 14:32:02 | Soil_dry | None | 3 | 3 |
| 2020-12-16 14:53:48 | Soil_dry | ul5 | 3 | 3 |
| 2020-12-16 14:54:52 | Soil_dry | ul5 | 3 | 3 |
| 2020-12-16 15:06:53 | soil_wet | ul5 | 3 | 3 |
| 2020-12-16 15:11:02 | soil_wet | ul5 | 3 | 3 |

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Kristian Jr.! With your solution not all values of X in df2 are in the final table. Getting multiple Jar/Treament for each X value is not a problem.

Comment: @Tiptop, the full_join does exactly what you’re describing: you will get all values of X. Try cutting down your df to a few values where you know X will be matched to a few jar/treatment values and where you know X will not be matched. In this way, you’ll see that all values are there - match or no match. :) or maybe I don’t get the problems. Try make an example of the result df you want.

Comment: Really? I will check tomorrow when I have my laptop. 

I will get all values of X yes. But in some rows I will get a value of X but an NA for Jar/Treatment. E.g. in df2 there is a value of X at Timestamp: 2020-12-16 14:31:05, but this Timestamp is not present in df1 and I will therefore get NA in Jar/Treatment. Based on df1 however, I know that at this time and date Jar=Soil_dry and Treatment=None.

Comment: But I will check with a small dataset as you suggest tomorrow!

Comment: I think this actually works: left_join(df2, df1) %>% fill(Jar, Treatment)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this either by `merge` as pointed out previously, or with `dplyr`:

```
left_join(df2, df1, "Timestamp")
#    X           Timestamp      Jar Treatment
# 1  34 2020-12-16 14:27:52     <NA>      <NA>
# 2   5 2020-12-16 14:28:54     <NA>      <NA>
# 3   5 2020-12-16 14:22:57     <NA>      <NA>
# 4  24 2020-12-16 14:30:34     <NA>      <NA>
# 5  45 2020-12-16 14:31:03 Soil_dry      None
# 6  66 2020-12-16 14:31:52 Soil_dry      None
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Ben. I think I did a pour job at describing my question. The problem with the ```join``` solution is that I also want to know what Jar and Treatment was when X was 34, 5, 5, 24 in row 1:4 in the table you made.